# C++/CMake:Undefined reference to imwrite in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, image-processing, cmake

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(proj)
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/lib/opencv")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core imgproc highgui)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test test.cpp>
target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

and this is part of my code:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{       
    //other code
    Mat img(height, width, CV_8UC3);
    //other code

    imwrite("/path", img);
    namedWindow( "Display window", 1 );
    imshow("Display window", img);

    waitKey(0);                                          
    return 0;

}
```

and the error message I get is:

```
undefined reference to cv::imwrite(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)`
```

imshow works correctly, so I have no clue why imwrite is giving me an error.

EDIT:

```
g++ -o test_1 test_1.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

gives the same error.

Comment: You're probably using OpenCV 3.x where they've moved some of the image processing code (including `imwrite`) to `<opencv/imgcodecs.hpp>`.

Comment: I'm using version 2.0, and I know for sure that it's in highgui.hpp :/ @beaker

Comment: According to "EDIT", your problem is not with CMake but with OpenCV installation. What output of `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev -I/usr/include/opencv  -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux -lml

Answer (score 1):

In your `find_package()` command, you are only selecting some specific modules from the **OpenCV** package, and the one you need (`imgcodecs` which provides `imwrite()`) is not in the list.

Try changing it to:

```
find_package(OpenCV)
```

Comment: In opencv 3.0 they splitted highgui into imgcodecs, videoio and highgui. So for <3.0 you can do with only importing highgui, but on >=3.0 you need to add this imgcodecs import (and videoio if you're using it).