# C++ fast way to save image from array of values

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, bitmap, cimg

Right now, I am using CImg.
I am unable to use OpenCV due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165791/c-cmakeundefined-reference-to-imwrite-in-opencv) issue.

My CImg code looks like this:

```
cimg_library::CImg<float> img(512,512); 
cimg_forXYC(img,x,y,c) { img(x,y,c) = (array[x][y]); } //array contains all float values between 0/1
img.save(save.c_str()); //taking a  lot of time
```

By using clocks I was able to determine that the first step, the for loop takes 0-0.01 seconds. However, the second step, the saving of the image, takes 0.06 seconds, which is way too long due to the amount of images I have.

I am saving as bitmaps.
Is there any faster way to accomplish the same things (creating an image from an array of values and save) in C++?

Comment: in `save.c_str()` what is `save` ?

Comment: @tobi303 it is a string, the value is about 110 characters depending on the image. It is /home/user/folder/longname.

Comment: What format are the files in when you save them? What format do you want? What's in your array? Why `float`?

Comment: @Omnifarious the filepath ends in .bmp. I don't really care about the format as long as the image shows up well and bitmap worked best. In my array are a bunch of float values between 0 and 1. I chose float because that's what the tutorial I used used. Is there a better option? Thank you for your response!

Comment: What's the format of your image?  What is the pixel depth?  Is each element a pixel?  Can your image have fractional pixels?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sorry, I am unsure what you mean by "my image"? I just have a 2d array with a bunch of floats between 0 and 1. I end up with a bitmap. I hope that helps with your questions. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Do the floats represent grayscale values? Is each one basically a measure of how black or white the pixel is?

Comment: @Omnifarious yes, essentially!

Comment: I'm tempted to write an extremely stupid PNG encoder that does no compression, just for this case. It should be pretty darned fast.

Comment: @Omnifarious if you have the time, would you mind trying, please?? I'm a total beginner to this. I'll keep researching if you cannot though :)

Comment: Writing your own bitmap encoder is fairly straightforward. I can't help feeling that your time would be better spent getting opencv up and running, however.

Comment: @Rook I would love to have opencv up and running but that question (associated with an account that no longer exists) hasn't really gotten enough attention. I also sent it to an opencv mailing list three weeks ago to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small function that will save your image in [pgm format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html), which most things can read and is dead simple. It requires your compiler support C++11, which most do. It's also hard-coded to 512x512 images.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>

void save_image(const ::std::string &name, float img_vals[][512])
{
   using ::std::string;
   using ::std::ios;
   using ::std::ofstream;
   typedef unsigned char pixval_t;
   auto float_to_pixval = [](float img_val) -> pixval_t {
      int tmpval = static_cast<int>(::std::floor(256 * img_val));
      if (tmpval < 0) {
         return 0u;
      } else if (tmpval > 255) {
         return 255u;
      } else {
         return tmpval & 0xffu;
      }
   };
   auto as_pgm = [](const string &name) -> string {
      if (! ((name.length() >= 4)
             && (name.substr(name.length() - 4, 4) == ".pgm")))
      {
         return name + ".pgm";
      } else {
         return name;
      }
   };

   ofstream out(as_pgm(name), ios::binary | ios::out | ios::trunc);

   out << "P5\n512 512\n255\n";
   for (int x = 0; x < 512; ++x) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 512; ++y) {
         const pixval_t pixval = float_to_pixval(img_vals[x][y]);
         const char outpv = static_cast<const char>(pixval);
         out.write(&outpv, 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get the error `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘float_to_pixval’ with no type` on the auto float_to_pixval line. Is this a compiler issue like you mentioned above the code?

Comment: @user8149522 - I don't know what compiler you are using, but try adding -std=c++11 to the command line for the compiler or doing whatever you need to turn on C++11 support. This code requires C++11. And yes, that's the issue I mentioned above. It can be re-written to not need C++11... that'd be a pain and it wouldn't look as nice.

Comment: Sorry, I know this wasn't part of the original question, but would you happen to know of a way I can take a pgm and get an array of values? In other words, the output to the input? I'm fine posting this as a separate question, I just didn't think it warranted one.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar vein to @Omnifarious's answer, there is an extremely simple format (also based on NetPBM concepts) for float data such as yours. It is called `PFM` and is documented [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pfm.html).

The benefit is that both **CImg** and **ImageMagick** are able to read and write the format without any additional libraries, and without you needing to write any code! An additional benefit is that you retain the full tonal range of your floats, rather than just 256 steps. On the downside, you do need the full 4 bytes per pixel rather than 1 byte.

So, your code would become:

```
CImg<float> img(512,512); 
cimg_forXYC(img,x,y,c) { img(x,y,c) = (array[x][y]); }
img.save_pfm("filename.pfm");
```

I benchmarked this by creating 10,000 images and saving them to disk with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#define cimg_display 0        // No need for X11 stuff
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

#define W   512
#define H   512
#define N   10000

int main() {
    // Create and initialise float image with radial gradient
   cimg_library::CImg<float> img(W,H); 
   cimg_forXY(img,x,y) {img(x,y) = hypot((float)(W/2-x),(float)(H/2-y)); }

   char filename[128];
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
      sprintf(filename,"f-%06d.pfm",i);
      img.save_pfm(filename);
   }
}
```

It runs in 21.8 seconds, meaning 2.1 ms per image (0.002s).

As I mentioned earlier, **ImageMagick** is also able to handle `PFM` format, so you can then use **GNU Parallel** and **ImageMagick** `mogrify` to convert those images to `JPEG`:

```
parallel -X mogrify -format jpg -auto-level ::: *pfm
```

For the original 10,000 images, that takes 22 seconds, or 2.2 ms/image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It looked really promising but after running this, the resulting JPGs were just plain white :( if it makes a difference, I wasn't able to use `parallel` so didn't use that.

Comment: You need to use the `-auto-level` option... `convert input.pfm -auto-level output.jpg`

Comment: Nope, I used your exact code and where you got that radial gradient, I got a plain white image :(

Comment: I have thunk! D'oh! I am using the Q32 HDRI (32-bit) version of ImageMagick to handle floats, whereas a default installation will be Q16 (16-bit). You can check with `identify -version`.

Comment: You're right, it's Q16! Is there a way to accomplish this through that?

Comment: If you want to deal with floats, you have to have Q32 - no way around it. Not sure of your platform/OS, but it is easy enough to build a Q32 version on most platforms.